# Why the use of 'RenderTargetBitmap' class makes GDI handle count increase?

Tags: c#, wpf, gdi, rendertargetbitmap

### My understandings

1) The classes inside 'System.Windows.Media' uses directx for rendering.
   It will not use GDI+. 
2) Only classes in 'System.Drawing' uses GDI+ for drawing.( This can cause GDI handle count increase.)

### Issue

But when I use 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap' for rendering a bitmap, the GDI count seems to be increased.

Why it happens so?

( Since I need to place these images on a button, and this button is part of the celltemplate of a Grid control, I want to reduce the GDI usage.)

```
DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
// Create Rectangle
Rect rect = new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), new System.Windows.Point(100, 100));
// Draw Rectangle
System.Windows.Media.Pen pen = new System.Windows.Media.Pen();
pen.Brush = Brushes.Black;
pen.Thickness = 5;
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, pen, rect);             
drawingContext.Close();
RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(100, 100, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
//Render DrawingVisual 
bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
```

Comment: Because it converts an visual object to an bitmap, and and bitmap needs a GDI handle.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, that's my understanding.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is going on there. Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9034362/1136211

Comment: @Clemens Yes, but no clue about why it takes GDI handle for drawing  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking around the net and some analysis, it seems that RenderTargetBitmap doesn't take advantage of hardware rendering(Direct X). It still uses GDI+ for rendering the bitmap offline.

It may be an exception to the common understanding about WPF rendering.
But its surprise me that MSDN doesn't provide a clue anywhere regarding this.